# why does these partition gaps occur?

Tags: partition, disk, ntfs

I am doing an experimental project on NTFS and I just discovered every time I create a new partition there seems to be a (nearly 1MB) partition gap created just before the new partition.

[image]

I searched in google and no specific answer could be found why these gaps occur. And what information does this gaps contain? I found most of my partition gaps empty.

As these gaps are only visible to the forensic tools (not by disk management of windows), if I want to use these  gaps (might require formatting) and create small partitions will it cause any damage to my system or boot sectors (MBR and VBRs)?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: maybe related : https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/150662/30851 -

Comment: In your case it also seems MiB alignment related, even though the first partition is not aligned at all (1st sector 63). In any case, the gaps do not cause any harm, they might even be useful in case there is ever a off-by-one error or something.

Comment: @frostschutz thanks for the link.  It helped a lot.

Comment: @frostschutz SO, if I format or wipe the gaps ---it will not cause any damage to my pc from loading logical drives? Am I right?

Comment: If those are logical partitions under an msdos extended partition (not clear from your picture), wiping the gaps would damage the partition table.

Comment: @frostschutz, how do I know my logical partitions are under an msdos extended partition? I created those partitions using the windows Disk Management tool.

Comment: You have an MBR partition table with five(5) partitions showing in WinHex. Therefore, since the maximum number of logical partitions are four(4) without extended partitions, you have extended partitions. GNU _parted_ shows you that information much more clearly.